# Is it good practice to have separate @SpringBootApplication for (junit) test and how

Tags: spring, jpa, junit, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application initially setting on `MySQL`, so far so good. However now I am trying to create more unit test for `JPA` / `DAO layer` with `H2` database.

I see several online demo that in Spring it is common practice to have an `applicationContext-test` for testing context setting.

Is it still good practice in Spring boot 1.4?

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {...})
public class ApplicationTest extends SpringBootServeltIntializer{
    ....
}
```

As currently there is no separate xml file holding context for testing, is above looks like a good solution? And also is there performance impact that when the application starts all context for testing are also need to loaded in memory?

Also does that mean I need to create an `application.properties` in test sources? Spring boot has a lot of implicit process behind, but I cannot find much texts explain about the DAO layer setting for test in Spring Boot, so any guideline is appreciated.

Comment: Spring Boot has support for (unit) testing, see [40. Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing) in the Spring Boot reference documentation.

Answer (score 3):

My preference is to not use Spring for JUnit testing at all.

JUnit tests, by definition, should be about unit testing individual classes.  Spring is a DI engine for satisfying dependencies.  Using the real dependencies breaks the idea of a unit test; for those I manually inject mocks.

I do that to restrict the tests to individual classes.  I find that creating the Spring factory and all the application beans takes a long time.  I don't want to pay that price when I have a lot of unit tests.  Keeping Spring out of the mix makes my tests run faster.

Comment: Thanks, that's a breeze of fresh air. However if DAO / JPA / Persistence are all relying on Spring framework, how to junit test without Spring context? Just through JDBC API?

Comment: Testing a DAO without a relational database makes no sense, but for those all I need is a java.sql.DataSource.  I can create one using the simple DriverManagerDataSource.  JPA and ORM are unnecessary for me.  If you use those, you have my sympathy.

Comment: I agree the point. So better I will create a connection class to test DAO layer. Sounds good :)